# SAS help on writing do loop

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a loop to flag two criteria. First if the difference between lag(timeperiod) - timeperiod >=4 and then to compare if diag codes between time periods is the same of different. I want to run the loop over each patientID until one of these criteria's are met.

TIA!

E.g. data

```
patientID, timeperiod, combined

wh7,1, diag1_diag2_diag3

wh7, 4, diag1_diag2_diag3_diag4

wh7, 10, diag1_diag2

wh7 15, diag4_diag10

wh4, 2, diag5_diag11_diag16

wh4, 4, diag5_diag11
```

Comment: Would you want to compare separated diag or combined diag? How would you like to show possible differences?

Comment: Share a few observations of data for 2 or 3 patients and show what result you want for the example data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BY` group processing and automatic `FIRST.` variable to test for when group has changed.  Also, understand that `and` expressions in SAS do not shortcut during evaluation - all compound expressions are fully evaluated.

Your DATA Step would be something like

```
data want;
  set have;
  by patientID;
  if not first.patientID and dif(time_period) >=4 and combined ne lag(combined) then 
    flag = 1;
  else 
    flag = 0;
run;
```

Note: `DIF(x)` is equivalent to `x - LAG(x)`